# Why am I getting 400 bad request when calling a .Net 2.0 web service from WCF over https?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, iis-6

I have a web service that contains a method I need to run to generate a report. The web service method is written in .Net 2.0 and works fine on my test system which runs on the same server as the live system. The only difference is that the live version uses https.

Whenever I change the endpoint address to the live service and run my application I only get 400(bad request) errors back from IIS.

Is there some specific configuration setting I need to change in the WCF settings in the app.config to get it to work with https?

The generated app.config settings created by "Add service reference" are as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ReportsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport" >
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

        <endpoint address="https://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir/Reports.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportsSoap"
            contract="SystemReports.ReportsSoap" name="ReportsSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It may also be relevant that I am on an intranet and external hostnames are accessed through a proxy that requires authentication. I have tried changing it to access from the IP but WCF complains that the certificate is invalid(because it looks at the host name)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to change binding configuration to use transport security.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="YourCurrentBindingName" ...>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: It was already there. I have changed it to be more like what you described but it still gives the same error. I have included my generated binding configuration in the question now.